# simple angularjs 2.0 example using typescript

Tags: typescript, angular

Be a dear, and help me with this simple Angularjs 2.0 example using typescript.

**What have I tried?**

I will provide my index.html and plunker the rest (I am sure there are more than a few issues in the plunker link below), **I am just starting** `AngularJS 2.0` `+` `typescript`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 Todo</title>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        typescriptOptions: {emitDecoratorMetadata: true},
        packages: {app: {defaultExtension: 'ts'}}
    });
    System.import('app');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app>Loading</app>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Plunker Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/dYDaBUFMvEqqwds0GfmL?p=info)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It doesn't run...visit my plunker...

Comment: Just use `New > AngularJS > 2.0.x (TS)` in Plunker to get a running Plunker with a recent Angular version (beta.9 is outdated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2.min.js"></script>`

but importing your directives with rc syntax`'@angular/common';`

Here's a simple plunker with rc.1 for a start: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kDfEeSto3TI4lkNGeqTz?p=preview)